# The topologies for which a presheaf is a sheaf?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, sheaf-theory

Given a set $S$, let $Top(S)$ denote the partially ordered set (poset) of topologies on $S$, ordered by fineness, so the discrete topology, $Disc(S)$, is maximal.

Suppose that $Q$ is a presheaf on $Disc(S)$, that $\tau$ is a topology on $S$, and that $\epsilon\colon Disc(S)\to (S,\tau)$ is the canonical map. I'll say that $Q$ is *a sheaf with respect to $\tau$* if the direct image presheaf $\epsilon_*(Q)$ is a sheaf.

For a given set $S$ and presheaf $Q$, let 
$$Top_{Q}(S)\subseteq Top(S)$$ 
denote the subposet of topologies on $S$ for which $Q$ is a sheaf.

For example, if $1$ is the terminal presheaf then $Top_{1}(S)=Top(S)$, i.e., every topology makes $1$ a sheaf. In general $Top_{Q}(S)$ may be empty, e.g., if $Q$ assignes a non-terminal set $Q(\emptyset)\not\cong\{*\}$ to the emptyset $\emptyset\subseteq S$.

**Question 1:** In general, what can one say about the poset $Top_Q(S)$? For example, is it closed under binary meets or joins in $Top(S)$?

Let $Top^{sep}_Q(S)$ denote the poset of $S$-topologies on which $Q$ is a separated presheaf. Recall that a presheaf on a space $X$ is separated if every matching family of sections on a cover extends to at most one section on their union. This condition is less stringent than the sheaf condition, which replaces *at most one* with *exactly one*. In general, we have 
$$Top_Q(S)\subseteq Top^{sep}_Q(S).$$ 
For example the initial presheaf $0$ on $Disc(S)$ is a separated presheaf but not a sheaf, so $Top_0(S)\subsetneq Top^{sep}_0(S)$.

**Question 2:** What can one say about the poset $Top^{sep}_Q(S)$?

---

Edit provenance: I added the second paragraph to address a question of Zhen Lin, which pointed out an ambiguity in the phrase "topologies on $S$ for which $Q$ is a sheaf." Later I added even more detail about that notion, to coincide with clarifications made in the comments. Even later, I realized that the notion I had originally chosen (that $Q$ was the inverse image presheaf $\epsilon^{-1}(Q')$ of some sheaf $Q'$ on $(S,\tau)$) was a bit pathological, so I weakened the condition to say that $\epsilon_*Q$ is a sheaf.

Comment: There seems to be a subtlety in the predicate "$Q$ is a sheaf". For instance, if $Q (\emptyset) = 1$, then is $Q$ automatically a sheaf for the indiscrete topology? Or do we also require that $Q (V) \to Q (U)$ be a bijection for all $\emptyset \subsetneq U \subseteq V \subseteq S$?

Comment: @ZhenLin, I don't understand. Are you asking whether $\emptyset\to X$ covers $X$ in the indiscrete topology on $X\neq \emptyset$? I think this definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology#Small_site_associated_to_a_topological_space would say "no".

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Rather, there are two reasonable interpretations of your condition: one only considers $Q (V)$ for open $V \subseteq S$, and another considers _all_ $V \subseteq S$.

Comment: Given a topological space $X$, by a presheaf on $X$, I mean a functor $F\colon Open(X)^{op}\to Set$. In the indiscrete topology, only $\emptyset$ and $S$ are open, so I consider them to be the only objects on which the presheaf (or sheaf) $F$ is defined.

Comment: I think Zhen's point is that for two different topologies on the same set, the notions of "presheaf" are different since they are functors on a different poset of opens.  So when you talk about topologies S "for which Q is a sheaf", you should really say topologies S "for which the restriction of Q to S is a sheaf" (assuming that that's what you mean).

Comment: Ah, thanks @MikeShulman. Edited to clarify the point.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused.  A presheaf doesn't have an inverse image along a continuous map.  It has an inverse image along a *functor*, but the functor associated to a continuous map goes in the other direction.

Comment: Suppose given a continuous map of topological spaces, $f: X\to Y$. I prefer the functor perspective: we have a functor $Open(f): Open(Y)^{op}\to Open(X)^{op}$. It induces a functor $M_f: Pre(Open(X))\to Pre(Open(Y))$ by composition, where for $C$ a category, $Pre(C)$ denotes the category of functors $C^{op}\to Set$. In the topological setting, $M_f$ would be denoted $f_*$, the direct image functor. It has a left adjoint $L_f$ and a right adjoint $R_f$. By $f^{-1}$, I mean the left adjoint. Is there a better name for this than "inverse image presheaf"?

Comment: @MikeShulman, does the above comment clarify?

Comment: Ah, okay.  That's very different from what I originally thought you meant!  I don't think I've ever heard anyone call this an "inverse image presheaf" -- I would call $M_f$ the "inverse image" along the functor $\mathrm{Open}(f)$ and $L_f$ the left Kan extension.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that $Q'$ is uniquely determined when it exists?

Comment: @MikeShulman, Yes. If $X=Disc(S)$ is discrete, $Y=(S,\tau)$, and $f: X\to Y$ is the counit, then $Open(f): Open(Y)^{op}\to Open(X)^{op}$ is fully faithful. Therefore the unit $\eta$ of the adjunction $(L_f,M_f)$ above is an isomorphism. So if we have $L_fQ'\cong Q$, we can apply $M_f$ and compose with the isomorphism $\eta_{Q'}: Q'\to M_fL_f(Q')$ to find an isomorphism $Q'\cong M_f Q$.

Comment: Right, silly me.

Comment: Have you worked this out in the case when $S$ has two elements?

Comment: Yes, and it looks a bit wacky. At least there, the "sheafy" topologies are closed under binary meets, but not 0-ary meets. However, the poset of topologies is tiny (a square), and so there isn't much to see.

Perhaps it be more interesting to ask for topologies $\tau$ for which the direct image presheaf $\epsilon_*Q$ is a sheaf (where $\epsilon:Disc(S)\to (S,\tau)$).